# "Inline C"-question

Tags: c, perl, types, inline

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.012;
use Inline 'C';

my $value = test();
say $value;

__END__
__C__
void test() {
    int a = 4294967294;
    Inline_Stack_Vars;
    Inline_Stack_Reset;
    Inline_Stack_Push( sv_2mortal( newSViv( a ) ) );
    Inline_Stack_Done;
}
```

Output:

```
-2
```

Why do I get here an output of "-2"?

Comment: So I don't have do write "use strict; use 5.010;". And so I know the century of the last edition of the file;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int a` uses probably 32-bit representation. You should use `unsigned int` if you want to represent values above 4,294,967,296/2.

Comment: That won't help, except on a perl with 64-bit int support.

Answer (score 5):

Perl supports both signed and unsigned integers, and its operators will switch nicely between them, but you are explicitly requesting an IV (signed int type SV).  Use newSVuv instead.  You also need to say `UV a =` or `unsigned a =` instead of int if ints are 32 bits but perl is using 64 bit integers, since otherwise the cast to UV done by newSVuv will end up extending the sign bit through the upper 32 bits.

Comment: When I only change newSVuv without "UV a =" I get a different result.

Comment: @sid_com: ah, if you have perl using 64 bit ints but an "int" is 32 bits, you need both?